# jQuery Ajax failing to call to Controller Action Result when deployed to server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-7

In my MVC 4, the code below is not calling controller action when deployed to the server. but it is working on my local.

I am using IE 7. 
THANKS IN ADVANCE.

js code:

```
    $("#button").click(function () {
    var uploadFile = document.getElementById("myFile").value;
    var fullPath = document.getElementById('myFile').value;
    var urlRegisterPartner = $('#registerurl').data('register-url'); 

    if (fullPath) {
        var startIndex = (fullPath.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\') : fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
        var filename = fullPath.substring(startIndex);
        if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
            filename = filename.substring(1);
        }
        $("#myModal").dialog("open");

        $.get(urlRegisterPartner, { uploadFile: uploadFile }, function (data) {
            alert(data.Messages);
            $("#myModal").dialog("close");
        });
    }
    else {
        alert('Please select file to upload');
    }
});
```

actionresult:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Upload(string uploadFile)
    {
        Message msg = new Message();

        string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFile/") + Path.GetFileName(uploadFile);
        msg.Messages = uploadRepo.ReadFile(uploadFile, fileLocation);

        return Json(msg, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: which jQuery version are you using? jQuery already [dropped support of IE7](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/06/28/jquery-core-version-1-9-and-beyond/); last version supporting IE7 is 1.9.x (Come on, time to update your browser, it's year 2015 now)

Comment: v 1.10.2. i know, I can't do anything. they're still using this outdated browser. Btw, I also tried this code using Chrome/Firefox yet still not working.

Comment: then go with 1.9.x jquery version or below than that and give a try!

Comment: so what errors are thrown? Have you checked network tab to see file load status? If it was me I would debug modern browser(better tools)  and work backwards

Comment: tnx for the reply. tried doing that, still not working. Why is that when I run this on my local pc it's working?

Comment: I have been facing the same issue. When ran the debugger in IE (F12) it always show "pending".